# hot plug sata to ESXi 5 server

Tags: vmware-esxi, sata, hotswap

Is it possible to hot plug an eSATA drive to an ESXi 5 server?

I'm exploring backup solutions and hoping to hot add a datastore, copy my VM's over, then hotunplug.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you can hot add USB drives.

Comment: Would you consider backing up from *within* the VMs?

Comment: No - hoping to backup the set of files which comprise the VM.

Comment: That is not the right way to back them up.  You should really use vsphere and script it; there is an API for that.

Comment: Watch out for non-quiesced VM images. What you're backing up may very well be corrupt if you haven't quiesced the guest itself and then frozen the guest filesystem during backup (snapshots of some kind typically take care of this). This is what the vSphere API an guest tools are for, as Falcon Momot mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

It does! I just used this feature recently.

Comment: A bit more detail would improve this answer

Comment: Well, I plugged the hard drive in and clicked the "check for new storage devices" button in the storage configuration. That's it.

Comment: Anybody else tested this? Please upvote the answer if it worked.

Comment: If it doesn't work, the sata controller on your motherboard probably doesn't support hotplug.

Comment: I could not reproduce this (and my hd controller supports hot swap).  I saw errors in the VM syslog, but no new drives available.  W